# getting error in reshap command in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am coding a script and I need to use reshape command.

This is my code:

```
Bit_Num=4; 
FFT_Num=64; 
Carrier_Num=48;
OFDM_per_Symbol=1; 
CP=16;  
LI=12 ; 
Np=4; % Number of pilot
Carriers=1:Carrier_Num+Np;
N_Num=Bit_Num*Carrier_Num*OFDM_per_Symbol;
BitTx=randi(1,N_Num);
N_Num=length(BitTx);
SymQAMtmp=reshape(BitTx,4,N_Num/4).';
```

I was coding with Matlab 2015 and it was okay. However, I need to run my code in Matlab 2017.

I got this error:

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

can anyone help me to fix this problem?

Comment: `randi(1,N_num)` generates a `N_num`-by-`N_num` matrix with random integers between 1 and 1, i.e. it's the same as `ones(N_num)`. What are you expecting it to give you?

Comment: If you want a `N_num`-by-`1` array of random 32 bit values you can use `randi([0, intmax('uint32')], N_Num, 1, 'uint32')`

Comment: in Matlab 2015 I have done it with randint command instead of randi. in 2017 I needed to replace it with randi :/

Answer (score 0):

You should read how 'randi' works. type 'help randi' to see that randi(1, N_Num) generates N_Num x N_Num matrix containing all elements '1'.